# How to get comment content from Youtube Activity List Comment type

Tags: youtube-api

In Youtube API v3, the activity list endpoint returns many activities for various type. Surprisingly the contentDetails return very little information. In terms of comment type, it seems to return only what you have commented to, but no comment identifier nor the actual comment content.

Is there a good way to identify what the user has commented with reference to the exact comment activity?

Answer (score 0):

V3 is still incomplete, some snippet.types like comment aren't available as of now but should be added before api v2 is phased out on 20th April 2015.[youtube's v3 migration blog](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2014/03/committing-to-youtube-data-api-v3.html)

we use this endpoint

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet,id,contentDetails&mine=true
```

and parameters to retrieve user's

> recommendation, likes, upload, subscription, bulletin

while the full list should be

> bulletin, channelItem, comment, favorite, like, playlistItem, recommendation,
>   social, subscription, upload

**comments don't come in this list as of now.**

but to get all comments on a particular video you can use their deprecated v2 api endpoint for now

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments
```